# Duplicate users being created by... something!

Tags: contacts

I have been trying to unpick a mystery now for a week without success! I wonder if anyone can help.

We have two contacts (out of a database of c 7,500) where we're seeing some odd behaviour.

As an example - let's call him John Doe.

John Doe has a contact record, linked to a Wordpress user account. He has registered for an event recently (may or may not be relevant). His record has a linked current employer, job title, and address.

Every day at 12:13pm or 12:14pm, a duplicate John Doe account appears in CiviCRM, according to the change log created by John Doe,  with matching:

- Name
- Email

But without

- Linked Wordpress account
- Job Title
- Current Employer

I am at a loss to explain why.  Things I have tried:

- Disabling the Capitalisation Correction Extension
- Disabling CiviRules
- Examining the scheduled jobs log

Cron runs every five minutes. The Scheduled Jobs log shows that between 12:10 and 12:15pm each day, there are no scheduled jobs running:

> 2020-02-20 12:10:02 Finishing scheduled jobs execution.
>
> 2020-02-20 12:15:05 Starting scheduled jobs execution

There are no scheduled jobs which uniquely run at 12:10pm.

For each contact, there is only one item in the change log:

[image: Change Log]

I'd be extremely grateful for any advice on investigating this further as I am now drawing a blank (and I have 36 John Does in the database!)

We are currently on 5.13.4 (security upgrade imminent)

Comment: One thing they have in common that I've just noticed - the day before this started happening, their accounts were merged with a duplicate. In both cases, the newly merged contact then inherited a membership from their employer.

Comment: Just to clarify - it may not be relevant - is it 12 am or pm? You've mentioned both, and it seems super-extra weird if it's pm.

Comment: @Demerit It is unfortunately the super-extra-weird pm!

Comment: Does the new contact created have full name or only email? Any inbound activity? What is your unsupervised dedupe rule?

Comment: Do you have detailed logging enabled?  That might provide a few more clues.

Comment: Hi @PradeepNayak - Full Name and email, no inbound activity. De-dupe is:

First Name - 5
Last Name - 5
Email - 5

Threshold: 15

Comment: @Aidan We certainly have logging enabled, not sure if it's detailed - I used the CiviCRM Log Viewer extension, and couldn't see anything relevant there - however, I am about to post a potential answer to this below!

Comment: Ah, different logging.  I'm meaning Administer > System Settings > Misc > Logging  If so, you'll have a load of SQL tables starting log_   Examining the recent changes for log_civicrm_contact might give you some clues

Comment: @Aidan That's helpful, thank you!  If the problem reoccurs I will start there

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by removing the user's current employer, saving the record, and then re-adding the current employer.  Seems potentially to have been some problem around the cascading membership?

Comment: Actually nothing to do with memberships - I have just created a fresh CiviCRM & WP install with 5 contacts, completely separate to the site above and with no memberships, and one of the contacts is cloning in almost  exactly the way they did on the other site - this time 2 contacts (min) every evening ‍♂️